# How do SetText label from thread class python

Tags: python

I've a Qt graphical interface.
How to refresh label text (lbl_serial_aff) from the thread

In the main file MainProg.py, i've a function starting a thread (ComWatcher) to scan a Serial port:

```
def RS232_RD_parametres_2(self):
    print('*** DEBUT *** RS232_RD_parametres 2 \r\n')
    watcher = ComWatcher()
    watcher.start()
```

In the Thread.py

```
import thread
import threading
import time
import serial
import tuto_form4

from tuto_form4 import *
from globalvar import *

class ComWatcher(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.running = False
        port = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0", baudrate=19200,  timeout=0.0) #
        print('start') 

    def run(self):
        global rd_parametre
        print('run')

        #tuto_formMain.self.aaa()
        #self.lbl_serial_aff.setText("None")

        """Le code que le thread devra exécuter."""
        port = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0", baudrate=19200,  timeout=0.0) #
        self.running = True
        while self.running:
            [.....]

    def stop(self):
        self.running = False
```

How can i do to change the Text of the label and everythings in the graphical interface?

```
lbl_serial_aff.setText("None")
```

Thanks,